# Derivation for 7.14 in Atomic Physics by Foot

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, laser, quantum-optics, atomic-physics

I was going thru Ch7 of Foot and trying to fill in the gaps. However I got stuck on (7.14). So Foot was working with a two level system with a small perturbation in the Hamiltonian resulted from an oscillating electric field $$H_I(t)=e\mathbf{r}\cdot \mathbf{E_0}cos(\omega t)$$.

Now we assume that the new eigenstate for the perturbed Hamiltonian is $$|\Psi(\mathbf{r},t)\rangle= c_1 |1\rangle e^{-i\omega_1 t}+c_2 |2\rangle e^{-i\omega_2 t}$$

And we work out relationships for $c_1$ and $c_2$ and try to solve them. It's not hard to get (7.9) and (7.10) in his book.

$$i\dot{c_1}=\Omega cos(\omega t)e^{-i\omega_0t}c_2$$
$$i\dot{c_2}=\Omega^* cos(\omega t)e^{i\omega_0t}c_1$$

where $\Omega$ is the Rabi frequency and $\omega_0=\omega_2-\omega_1$.

Now Foot says "when all the population starts in the lower level, $c_1(0)=1$ and $c_2(0)=0$. Integration of eqns (7.9) and (7.10) leads to

$$c_1(t)=1$$
$$c_2(t)=\frac{\Omega^*}{2}\{\frac{1-e^{i(\omega_0+\omega)t}}{\omega_0+\omega}+\frac{1-e^{i(\omega_0-\omega)t}}{\omega_0-\omega}\}"$$

I was wonder how we could integrate them and get those two eqns at the bottom? I tried two different ways but I still can't quite get what I want. Also I tried to simplify (7.9) and (7.10) a bit

$$i\dot{c_1}=c_2(e^{i(\omega-\omega_0)t}+e^{-i(\omega+\omega_0)t})\frac{\Omega}{2}$$

But not sure if this helps with the integration.

Any thoughts?

**My apologies for previous ambiguity. In particular, I apologise to @neutrino for asking the wrong question. The question is: We all know that it would make our lives much easier if we apply rotating wave approximation before solving the ODEs. However Foot solved the ODEs first to get this result $$c_1(t)=1$$
$$c_2(t)=\frac{\Omega^*}{2}\{\frac{1-e^{i(\omega_0+\omega)t}}{\omega_0+\omega}+\frac{1-e^{i(\omega_0-\omega)t}}{\omega_0-\omega}\}"$$ He then applied the rotating wave approximation. I was wondering if anyone could derive the above equation in the way that Foot did?**

Comment: It may be useful if you comment which ways have you tried.

Comment: I think your las equation should be: $$i\dot{c_1}=c_2(e^{i(\omega-\omega_0)t}+e^{-i(\omega+\omega_0)t})\frac{\Omega}{2}$$

Comment: @Nivalth Thanks for the comment. I tried the way neutrino did it. I also tried to do it by brute force. But the former does not give me the answer in the book. The later was a bit too complicated to work out.

Comment: @Evariste Are you sure that the book states that $c_1(t)=1$? In that case, (7.9) implies that $c_2(t)=0$, or $\Omega = 0$...

Comment: @Evariste I've confirmed that (7.9) is correct, I've been able to get a copy of Foot's book. But I don't know how to arrive to that solution, with $c_1(t)=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Schrödinger equation for a periodic electric potential is:
$$-\frac{\hbar}{i}\dot\psi=[H+E_{0}cos(\omega t)]\psi$$

Now, as you said, let's assume that the new eigenstate for the perturbed Hamiltonian is $$|\Psi(\mathbf{r},t)\rangle= c_1 |1\rangle e^{-i\omega_1 t}+c_2 |2\rangle e^{-i\omega_2 t} $$

Here $|1\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$ are solutions for the stationary state:
$$H|1\rangle = \hbar \omega _{1}$$
$$H|2\rangle = \hbar \omega _{2}$$

If you substitute $|\Psi(\mathbf{r},t)\rangle$ in the Schrödinger equation, and then, perform a scalar product with $\langle1|$ and $\langle2|$, you arrive at two differential equations, for $c_{1}(t)$ and $c_{2}(t)$:

$$i \hbar \dot{c_1}=cos(\omega t) (\langle1|E_{0}|1\rangle c_1 + \langle1|E_{0}|2\rangle c_2e^{-i(\omega_2-\omega_1)t})$$
$$i \hbar \dot{c_2}=cos(\omega t) (\langle2|E_{0}|1\rangle c_1e^{-i(\omega_1-\omega_2)t} + \langle2|E_{0}|2\rangle c_2)$$

Now, let's call $\omega_0 = \omega_2 - \omega _1$, and $\Delta \omega = \omega - \omega_0$, and assume that $\Delta \omega << \omega_0$, then the previous two equations can be written as:

$$i\dot{c_1}=\frac{1}{2\hbar} (\langle1|E_{0}|1\rangle c_1 (e^{i\omega t}+e^{-i\omega t})+ \langle1|E_{0}|2\rangle c_2(e^{i\Delta\omega t}+e^{-i(\omega+\omega_0) t}))$$
$$i\dot{c_2}=\frac{1}{2\hbar} (\langle2|E_{0}|1\rangle c_1 (e^{-i\Delta\omega t}+e^{i(\omega+\omega_0) t})+ \langle2|E_{0}|2\rangle c_2(e^{i\omega t}+e^{-i\omega t}))$$

Now, we can apply [Rotating Wave Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_wave_approximation) to discard the fast rotating terms with frequency $\omega$:
$$i\dot{c_1}=\frac{1}{2\hbar} (\langle1|E_{0}|2\rangle c_2(e^{i\Delta\omega t}+e^{-i(\omega+\omega_0) t}))$$
$$i\dot{c_2}=\frac{1}{2\hbar} (\langle2|E_{0}|1\rangle c_1 (e^{-i\Delta\omega t}+e^{i(\omega+\omega_0) t}))$$

Let's do the subsitution $\Omega = \frac {\langle1|E_{0}|2\rangle}{\hbar}$ to obtain:

$$i\dot{c_1}=c_2(e^{i(\omega-\omega_0)t}+e^{-i(\omega+\omega_0)t})\frac{\Omega}{2}$$
$$i\dot{c_2}=c_1(e^{-i(\omega-\omega_0)t}+e^{i(\omega+\omega_0)t})\frac{\Omega^{\star}}{2}$$

Then, apply again the [Rotating Wave Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_wave_approximation) to discard the fast rotating terms $\omega + \omega_0$, which are of order $2\omega$:

$$i\dot{c_1}=c_2e^{i(\omega-\omega_0)t}\frac{\Omega}{2}$$
$$i\dot{c_2}=c_1e^{-i(\omega-\omega_0)t}\frac{\Omega^{\star}}{2}$$

If you derive the first of the last two equations with respect to time:
$$i\ddot{c_1}=\dot{c_2}e^{i(\omega-\omega_0)t}\frac{\Omega}{2}+c_2i(\omega-\omega_0)e^{i(\omega-\omega_0)t}\frac{\Omega}{2}$$
You can eliminate $c_{2}$ from the second equation, obtaining a second order ODE. Then, try as an ansatz: $$c_{1}=Ae^{\lambda t}+Be^{-\lambda t}$$

And apply the initial conditions.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! It was a good answer. And personally I would do it this way(i.e. applying the rotating-wave approximation first). However I would really like to know how Foot got to this equation $$i\dot{c_1}=c_2(d^{i(\omega-\omega_0)t}+e^{-i(\omega+\omega_0)t})\frac{\Omega}{2}$$. He claims that he integrated the system of ODEs first before applying the rotating-wave approximation, which sounds a bit sus.

Comment: By the way, I voted your answer up. But forgive me for not accepting your answer for now(simply because I was looking for something else, i.e. the way Foot did this question).

Comment: @Evariste I've edited my answer to give you a more detailed explanation, including the derivation for the "problematic" Foot's equation.

Comment: I don't understand your notation, particularly the difference between $\omega$ and $\omega_0$. If $\omega$ is the difference in frequency between the two levels, then $\omega$ should be independent from the electric field frequency, which you called $\omega_0$. Yet, you seem to be using $\omega$ to refer to the electric field frequency also. This choice of notation makes it difficult to see how  you went from the first set of equations for the $\dot{c}$'s to the second. Am I not understanding something?

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs You're right, I made a mistake! Corrected!

Comment: @neutrino Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I realised that I made a mistake in my previous comment. What I was actually looking for was the derivation of these equations $$c_1(t)=1$$
$$c_2(t)=\frac{\Omega^*}{2}\{\frac{1-e^{i(\omega_0+\omega)t}}{\omega_0+\omega}+ \frac{1-e^{i(\omega_0-\omega)t}}{\omega_0-\omega}\}"$$
when I "copy and paste" from my previous question, I made such a mistake... I'm sorry for making you do more work(which wasn't necessary as I derived every step up to the system of ODEs already...).

Comment: @Evariste Please see my comment to your original post

Comment: @neutrino You're right. That seems really silly. I don't get why Foot skipped so many steps in an introductory textbook... Also it seems that he didn't apply the rotating wave approximation to get rid of the diagonal terms of the perturbative Hamiltonian.

Comment: @neutrino Anyway I should give you the credit. Otherwise it's going to be unfair. Although I really want to know how Foot arrive at 7.14

Comment: @Evariste Thank you! At least, we both have learned something about Rabi oscillations ;-)

Comment: @neutrino no worries. yeah definitely. it was my first time learning atomic physics.

Answer (score 0):

He used time-dependent perturbation theory to get the result without RWA. You can see Griffiths, introduction to quantum mechanics.